# MONACAにて作成したiOSアプリがアップローダーでエラーのためアップロードできません

Tags: ios, monaca

monacaにてアプリを作成しております
既存のiosアプリをアップデートのためアップローダでアップロードしましたが
以下のエラーメッセージでアップロードできませんでした
何度もアップデートしているアプリですので初歩的な問題ではないように思われます
アップローダーは3.0でだめだったため3.1にアップデートしましたがだめでした。
解決方法ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけますでしょうか？

ERROR ITMS-90085: “No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xcodの最新版をインストールすることでアップローダも最新になり解決しました。

Comment: `最新版`という書き方ではなく、バージョン番号を書くとより有益な回答になります。「バージョンxxxでは動かなかったが、バージョンxxxにアップデートしたら解決した」等の書き方に改め、回答を承認されると良いと思います。